# Using JavaScript Variable in PostBackUrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

I am trying to insert some JavaScript functions I am using for my QueryString in a URL.  I am working off of a DataGrid and calling the PostBackUrl off of an Insert command asp:LinkButton.  Here is my URL:

```
PostBackUrl="ETaskerComments.aspx?etasker=12345&subCat=2"
```

I am getting my QueryStrings in JavaScript from my jumper page and I want to replace the 12345 and the 2 in the subCat with my JavaScript variables.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Edit:

Let me try to clarify more...

I have two QueryStrings

```
var eTasker = getQueryParam("eTasker");
var subCat = getQueryParam("subCat");
```

I am wanting to get something like this:

```
PostBackUrl="ETaskerComments.aspx?eTasker=' + eTasker + '&subCat=' + subCat + '"
```

I though something like his would work but the asp:LinkButton does not like the syntax.  Hope this helps in the explaination.

Thanks

Comment: I think you haven't gotten an answer yet because the question is a little hard to understand.  Can you post some example code?  That would help clarify.  You can always use the javascript Replace() method to replace text, but I'm not sure that answers your question.

Comment: I have tried the replace method and it seems to not want to post back after execution.  This is being a pain in the @$$. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.  What I had to do was take the code completly out of the client side and move it to server side in order to interact with the DetailsView (I know I said DataGrid, should work the same either way) like I wanted.  The PostBackUrl does not appear to accept variables, so this can not be an option.  Also,  I ended up using meta tags in the head of the ASPX page to not cache the page.  Here is what I did:

Put these meta tags inside the head of the page to make sure your page does not cache.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Second, we are goign to make a C# event handler to capture the post back event and make the page reload where we want it, getting our QueryStrings in the process.

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">

protected void Post_Back(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string subCat = Request.QueryString["subCat"].ToString();
string eTasker = Request.QueryString["eTasker"].ToString();
if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    Response.Redirect("ETaskerComments.aspx?eTasker=" + eTasker + "&subCat=" + subCat + "&Dashboard_ID=" +subCat);

}


}
</script>
```

Now instead of attaching the Post_Back to the Insert with an OnClick, we are going to attach it to the DetailsView with the OnItemInserted parameter:

```
<asp:DetailsView DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserted="Post_Back" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="50px" id="DetailsView1" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" BackColor="#87AB7B" BorderColor="#1A120F" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" CellPadding="2">
```

That is it.  Make sure there are no more calls attached to the Insert command link and this should run your Command and refresh you DataGrid/DetailsView with the newly inserted record.

Thanks for all of the views.  Happy Coding! :)